# SQLite error running Android app

Tags: android, sqlite

I have been developing a simple application on android, where you enter a series of numbers and pressing a button, this information travels to another activity, where should be stored in a database,when you submit the number good, but the error is to use the functions in sqlite, according to the Logcat my mistake is syntax but I can not get to it, I'm new to developing for android

The Logcat

```
     Build Date: 12/12/12 Wed
    Local Branch:
    Remote Branch: m/jb_rel_2.0.3
    Local Patches: NONE
    Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_REL_2.0.3_RB3.04.01.01.42.002 +  NOTHING
02-04 16:12:56.247  10395-10395/austranet.myapplication2 E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) near "/": syntax error
02-04 16:12:56.247  10395-10395/austranet.myapplication2 W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40f7c438)
02-04 16:12:56.267  10395-10395/austranet.myapplication2 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{austranet.myapplication2/austranet.myapplication2.registro}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "/": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE ingresos(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,rut TEXT NOT NULL,fecha_registro DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,ingreso/salida TEXT);
```

the sqlite handler snapshot:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/T0iwxHa.png]

Comment: For your situation, you do not need the database, you can use `Intent.putExtra` or `sharedpreferences ` to achieve your goal

Answer (score 2):

Check out this field: `...,ingreso/salida TEXT);`.
It's an **invalid column definition**.

Use something like `ingreso_salida`

Or use (**strongly discouraged**) square brackets:
`...,[ingreso/salida] TEXT);`

Comment: OK. Is it worh, to have such a "dangerous" name?

Comment: Nope, see my comment above - I wouldn't recommend it as well. However, you cannot say it is invalid.

Comment: `/` is not a valid character. In facts, you have to use a **workaround**, to use it (the `[]`). I call this `[]` a **workaround** to fix an invalid character (coud be **/**, a space, a hyphen, ...).

Comment: In SQLite, using `[]` is a defined way to use reserved keywords in identifier names - though not recommended _"As a general rule
of thumb you should try to avoid using any keywords from the SQL language "_, see: http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CFwQFjAH&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcatalogue.pearsoned.co.uk%2Fsamplechapter%2F067232685X.pdf&ei=P3vSVODFLabD7gbL4YCADA&usg=AFQjCNHLKmaj1drS_q67iSYGos5cNhItsA

Comment: @Trinimon Anyway, `ingreso/salida` (**without brackets**) IS an **invalid name**.

Comment: I'm sorry to say this but, no! You can use it though I can only think of very rare situations where it might make sense (e.g in generic environments where code is generated automatically).

Comment: @Trinimon Not **without** brackets.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `/` in your column name you have to enclose it in brackets:

```
CREATE TABLE ingresos
  (_id              INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
   rut              TEXT NOT NULL,
   fecha_registro   DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   [ingreso/salida] TEXT);
```

Check out this [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/fef75/5). Find the documentation [here](http://catalogue.pearsoned.co.uk/samplechapter/067232685X.pdf), page 56. Note, that it is not recommended to use any kind of keywords in identifier names.

Comment: from the doc `This is not standard SQL.` double quote are the standard way to enclose an identifier.

Comment: @njzk2: It works with SQLite on Android devices (see tags). I know it's not standard SQL - may be even not nice to use. But it's possible ;)

Comment: @Trinimon: where in answers we are saying `it's not possible` ?? . we are saying `/` is not valid character for column name

Comment: It is valid but not recommend to use. Read the documentation (http://catalogue.pearsoned.co.uk/samplechapter/067232685X.pdf, page 56).

Comment: @Der Golem: There is a difference between a _column name_,  a _column definition_ and _meta symbols_. If you can, show me any Android SQLite documentation that states that `ingreso/salida` is an invalid _column name_. I'm sure you can't. (see https://www.sqlite.org/syntax/column-def.html, http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html)

Comment: @Der Golem: No documentation that proves your statement? BTW I discourage the use of keywords and special characters as well. But it is valid - otherwise SQLite would not execute the statement.

Comment: As I stated, it's **only** valid if you surround it with **brackets** (these things here: `[]`).

Comment: @Der Golem: according to the documentation it works with `""` and `''` as well. - and in fact it does. Note: the column name is always `ingreso/salida`, independently of the following definitions: `[ingreso/salida] text`, `'ingreso/salida' text` or `"ingreso/salida" text`. For the sake of freedom in this forum I'd like to make a suggestion: may I revise your answer slightly (and revert the down-vote consequently)?

Comment: See. What the OP did was `CREATE TABLE ... ingreso/salida TEXT);` which is **invalid** and caused the error. **IF** s/he did `CREATE TABLE ... [ingreso/salida] TEXT);`, **THEN** it would have been (forcibly) **valid**. And we wouldn't be here discussing about it. S/he also tried to insert values in it using the same **invalid name** `valores.put("ingreso/salida", tipo);` instead of the (forcibly) **valid name** `valores.put("[ingreso/salida]", tipo);`.

Comment: @Der Golem: now we get closer: "`CREATE TABLE ... ingreso/salida TEXT);` which is invalid ...", exactly, it's an invalid _column definition_. The _column name_ is (technically) valid if you embrace it with `[]`, `""` or `''`. Though, of course, not recommended at all.

Comment: Oh, well... it's just naming... The concepts remains. Mybe you're fresh of school (and maybe studied specifically). I started as an hobbyst over 30 years ago... OK, it's clear we both mean the same thing, but in 2 different ways. Yours being more accademically accurate. Mine being the long-term everyday developer... ;)

Comment: Ok, I admit, may be it's a bit niggling to point this difference out. But after 31 years of programming experience, a diploma in computer science and nearly 20 years in the job, I know that it's often quite important to be precise. I posted my answer for the very few people who need a solution for having special characters in a column name (just an as offer). For the rest, renaming the column to `ingreso_salida` is the much better solution. Ok to make some small adjustment to your post?

Comment: @Trinimon Yes, it's OK. Do it... So, my answer will look better. ;)

Answer (score 1):

``Current create table query have following issues :

**1.** `ingreso/salida` is invalid column name. use valid character in column name like `ingreso_salida`

**2.** column names missing space between column names. so using `String.format` to create valid sqlite query :

```
String tableQuery=String.format("CREATE TABLE %s (%s 
                                 INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                                 %s TEXT NOT NULL, 
                                 %s DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                                 %s TEXT)",  
                                "ingresos", "_id",  
                                "rut", "fecha_registro","ingreso_salida"));
```

Comment: Because of _"ingreso/salida is invalid column name"_. I think the point is, that you have to embrace the column point, if you want to use some particular characters such as `/`.

Comment: @Trinimon: you  mean `ingreso/salida` is valid name? where you read `/` is allowed in table and column names?

Comment: Yes, I just tried it with a real device (`adb shell ...`) and it worked pretty well. If you had said that the column _definition_ is wrong, I would have agreed. But the column _name_ is possible to use, though it might not be the best choice.

Comment: @Trinimon: man where in our answers we are saying column name is not possible  with any special characters? we are saying `ingreso/salida` is not possible i hope you agree with us. to fix issue your suggestion is use column name in `[]` (which is not sqlite standard naming conservation )  and we are saying use valid separator like `_` in column name words . then where is issue?? why you down-voting other answers?

Comment: Yes, I'd also like to know: why?

Comment: @Trinimon Anyway, `ingreso/salida` (**without brackets**) IS an **invalid name**.

Comment: No, because the column name will in fact be `ingreso/salida` - the bracket are only a kind of escape characters.

Comment: @Trinimon `the column name will in fact be ingreso/salida` **NO**. Without the "escape characters" you'll get an **error** and the column **won't be generated**.

Comment: @Der Golem: I would recommend that you try it yourself with a small sample. You will see that the reported column name is in fact `ingreso/salida` though you have to declare it as `[ingreso/salida]`. So the column name is `ingreso/salida` whereas the column definition for it uses `[ingreso/salida]`. We know this from other languages. In ORACLE, for example, you can use `""` to make columns case sensitive and `""` is not part of the column name. In Java we use `\\` in order to escape the back slash and it represents the character `\`. In an OS like VMS we use `[]` with directory names... Sorry!

Comment: Maybe you didn't read my comment correctly: `ingreso/salida` (**without brackets**) IS an **invalid name**. I said "without brackets". By the way, Access and **SQL Server** use `[]` too, for handling **invalid characters**.

Comment: OK, that's the correct name. So, what? The concept remains.